# Registering avalonia application to a custom URI Scheme

Tags: wpf, uwp, avaloniaui, avalonia, appxmanifest

Not too long ago I switched from MAUI to Avalonia and ran into a problem that I can't link `.appxmanifes` to a project to automatically register a custom url scheme in my app during local deployment (debugging).

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Solved this issue with my custom CallbackManager as a workaround.

Comment: Can you tell more about how you did this?

Comment: @Bagroy please expand on how you did it